# Representing a queue as a procedure with local state

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, sicp, mutation, first-class-functions

[Section §2.1.3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%25_sec_2.1.3) at page 90 explains,  with a very clear example, that first class functions in a language make functions themselves and data be the same thing looked at from different perspectives, or, to cite the book:

> the ability  to manipulate procedures as objects automatically provides the ability to represent compound data.

At page 266, exercise 3.22 from [Section §3.3.2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_3.3.2), proposes the following

> Instead of representing a queue as a pair of pointers, we can build a queue as a procedure with local state. The local state will consist of pointers to the beginning and the end of an ordinary list. Thus, the `make-queue` procedure will have the form
>
> ```lisp
> (define (make-queue)
>   (let ((front-ptr ...)
>         (rear-ptr ...))
>     <definitions of internal procedures>
>     (define (dispatch m) ...)
>     dispatch))
> ```
>
> Complete the definition of `make-queue` and provide implementations of the queue operations using this representation.

I easily came up with the following (I've used names `the-list` and `last-pair` instead of `front-ptr` and `rear-ptr` because I found it clearer, in this case):

```lisp
(define (make-queue)
  (let ((the-list '())
        (last-pair '()))
    (define (dispatch m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'empty) (null? the-list))
            ((eq? m 'front) (if (null? the-list)
                                (error "can't take front of empty list")
                                (car the-list)))
            ((eq? m 'ins) (lambda (e)
                            (if (null? the-list)
                                (begin (set! the-list (list e))
                                       (set! last-pair the-list))
                                (begin (set-cdr! last-pair (list e))
                                       (set! last-pair (cdr last-pair))))
                            the-list))
            ((eq? m 'del) (begin
                           (if (null? the-list)
                               (error "can't delete from emtpy list")
                               (set! the-list (if (pair? the-list) (cdr the-list) '())))
                           the-list))
            ((eq? m 'disp) (display the-list)) ; added this for convenience
            (else "error")))
    dispatch))

(define (empty-queue? q) (q 'empty))
(define (front-queue  q) (q 'front))
(define (insert-queue! q e) ((q 'ins) e))
(define (delete-queue! q) (q 'del))
(define (display-queue q) (q 'disp))
```

which seems to work pretty fairly well…

… except for one crucial point!

At the beginning of §3.3.2 the two desired mutators (that are part of the queue interface) are defined like this (my emphasis):

> `(insert-queue! <queue> <item>)`
>
> inserts the item at the rear of the queue ***and returns the modified queue as its value***.
>
> `(delete-queue! <queue>)`
>
> removes the item at the front of the queue ***and returns the modified queue as its value***, signaling an error if the queue is empty before the deletion.

My solution doesn't abide by those parts of the definition, because both `insert-queue!` and `delete-queue!` are returning `the-list`, which is the bare list, an implementation detail of the queue interface. Indeed, my solution doesn't support things like these

```lisp
(define q (make-queue)) ; ok
(insert-queue! (insert-queue! q 3) 4) ; doesn't work
(delete-queue! (delete-queue! q))     ; doesn't work
```

whereas I think it should.

I guess that the solution should see `delete-queue!` and `insert-queue!` return a mutated version of the `dispatch` function.

How do I do that?

Comment: In MIT/SCHEME this kind of representation of data structures is called a `Bundle`.  Read about bundles in mit/scheme, they are used everywhere to implement mit/scheme.  A bundle is a syntactic sugar for what you wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for that. Simply define

```
(define (insert-queue! q e) 
  ((q 'ins) e)
  q) 

(define (delete-queue! q) 
  (q 'del)
  q)
```

The design is not clean though, as in, these queues are not persistent. The new version and the old share the same underlying buffer (list). There is no old version preserved anymore, just the current version.

So we don't return a new, modified queue; we return the same queue which has been mutated. Conceptually, that is. On a little bit lower level, we return the same dispatch procedure which is a part of the same closure which holds the same internal binding for the internal buffer, which has been mutated.

By the way, using the head sentinel trick, were you start with e.g. `(list 1)` instead of `'()`, usually leads to much simplified, clearer code.

Comment: I feel so dumb.

Comment: Why you say _anymore_?

Comment: Just my idiosyncratic English. :) writing two sentences at once.

Comment: Btw to see "head sentinel" in action, you can search for it in my answers.

Comment: What I mean is, the book talks of returning the modified queue which sounds like implying there is the old unmodified version lying around somewhere, and there isn't one anymore, with the mutation. So there's some cognitive dissonance there. Maybe that's the authors way  to push the reader to ask himself, can it be made persistent, and how. The interface won't change, only the implementation (and the semantics) will.

Comment: @Enlico re your Fibonacci question, it was far too long ago, but that answer does seem to mention the possibility of a compiler retaining the memo list between calls for certain types of definitions, in which case a second call with the same (or smaller) argument shouldn't take time at all. otherwise, a compiler deciding entirely on its own to just retain a certain argument's result value is a completely different affair. but I'm certainly not an authority on these kinds of things -- *at all*.